# AttributeError: type object 'Word2Vec' has no attribute 'load_word2vec_format'

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to implement word2vec model and getting Attribute error

> AttributeError: type object 'Word2Vec' has no attribute 'load_word2vec_format'

Below is the code :

```
wv = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)
wv.init_sims(replace=True)
```

Please let me know the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gojomo's answer is right

`gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)`

try to upgrade all dependencies of gensim(e.g. smart_open), if you still have errors as follows

`pip install --upgrade gensim`

*File "/home/liangn/PythonProjects/DeepRecommendation/Algorithm/Word2Vec.py", line 18, in **init**
    self.model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_path, binary=True)*

File "/home/liangn/PythonProjects/venvLiang/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 191, in load_word2vec_format with utils.smart_open(fname) as fin:

File "/home/liangn/PythonProjects/venvLiang/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 138, in smart_open
    return file_smart_open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode)

File "/home/liangn/PythonProjects/venvLiang/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 642, in file_smart_open
    return compression_wrapper(open(fname, mode), fname, mode)

File "/home/liangn/PythonProjects/venvLiang/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 630, in compression_wrapper
    return make_closing(GzipFile)(file_obj, mode)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gzip.py", line 94, in **init**
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = **builtin**.open(filename, mode or 'rb')

**TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found**

Answer (score 2):

How did you install gensim, and what version is installed?

API changes in (currently pre-release) gensim 1.0 move `load_word2vec_format()` to a helper class called `KeyedVectors`.

At this point (February 2017) you probably don't want to be using a pre-release version unless you're an experienced gensim user and closely follow the release-notes `[CHANGELOG.md][1]`.

If intentionally using a later version of gensim with this API change, you would instead use:

```
KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)
```

Comment: I am new to gensim and using 1.0.0rc2. I tried using KeyedVector:

    import KeyedVectors
    KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)

but still I am getting the error. I am using Python 2.7, should I upgrade to Anaconda as some packages works good there

Comment: How did you install gensim? I don't believe `pip install gensim` would get you that pre-release version. What actual error are you getting after trying to use `KeyedVector`? (It can't possible be the same error, and the exact messages matter for solving.)