# Getting the Attribute Error: type object 'Word2Vec' has no attribute 'load_word2vec_format' while doing sentiment analysis

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, attributeerror, sentiment-analysis

word2vec = Word2VecProvider()
gensim.models.Word2Vec("glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt")

I have updated my gensim library twice but in vain. Any lead would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363897/attributeerror-type-object-word2vec-has-no-attribute-load-word2vec-format ?

Answer (score 0):

What is `Word2VecProvider`? (That's not a class in Gensim.) Also, this code wouldn't be proper Python:

```py
word2vec = Word2VecProvider() gensim.models.Word2Vec("glove.twitter.27B.200d.txt")
```

So, you may want to edit your question to more clearly show & format exacty the code that's triggering the error.

On the other hand, `gensim.models.Word2Vec` is a Gensim class. But, it doesn't take a string file path as an argument. So again, it's not clear how your code is related to your error.

And, if you're seeing an `AttributeError`, there should be more info – including a call stack showing all code involved. Cutting & pasting that full info into your question, well-formatted, would help clarify exactly what code/libraries might be involved in your error.